# Как считать данные с экрана? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть приложение, из которого надо считать данные в таблицу excel. Есть несколько столбцов: группа, кол-во, наименование, стоимость. Надо считать эти значения и перенести в соответствующие столбцы в таблице.

Как считать данные с изображения, без четкого текста, по аналогии поиска соответствия?
Как занести эти данные в таблицу excel?

Comment: То есть вы желаете считать какие-то данные из интерфейса приложения без какого-либо api, верно?

Comment: получать изображение с экрана можно с помощью PIL, распознавать текст с помощью tesseract